# Recuperar Json após success e usar no PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables

Tenho o código javascript que me retorna em uma variável 'msg' o resultado de uma consulta feita em PHP.

```
  var page = "busca.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: page,

        data: {idtabela: idtabela},
        success: function (msg) {
            //preciso transferir os dados no formato json par ao php
            msg = $.parseJSON(msg);              
        }
    });
```

Esse dados estão formato json, eu preciso transferir para um outro arquivo php.
Para ser mais preciso, eu estou usando o plugin DataTables. Nele já faço um laço de uma consulta sql no banco.
Agora eu preciso dar a opção ao usuário em qual tabela ele quer consultar, assim mudando a consulta a cada clique.
Pensei em fazer no arquivo onde está a tabela, uma variável que receba o json e jogue na DataTables

Comment: Com datatables vc pode fazer o carregamento inicial através de um ajax https://datatables.net/manual/ajax, é isso que você precisa?

Comment: Acho que é por ai a resposta, mas ainda não consegui jogar os dados no DataTable.